# iOS 11 how to prevent iBooks from moving my books to the cloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, books

I see that my iBooks seems to be uploading my books to the cloud without keeping a copy on my local device. So when I reopen the app, I have to wait for the book to do finish downloading (which is a hassle if it is a 600 page pdf)

**How can I prevent iBooks from deleting local book files and moving them to the cloud?**

Is this related to “offload I used apps” switch? (it’s on for me)

Comment: Please leave the feature request in https://www.apple.com/feedback/books-ios-ipados.html

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in iBooks.  Please report it to Apple so they fix it.  Many of us have this problem.  I just got bit by it on an airplane flight, when I realized I didn't have my books on my iPad or phone because... Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Preferences, uncheck options which reads `Sync bookmarks, highlights and collections across devices`

Comment: What if I still wanted my books (including bookmarks, highlights, collections) to be synced over iCloud, but not deleted from local storage automatically?

Comment: @BrunoEly so far couldn't find anything on it.