# How to stop iPhone from deleting local music?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, books

I download music to my iphone.

When I try to play the media offline some days or weeks later, it says I cannot because I am offline. They have cloud symbols next to them.

How can I stop this happening? I still have more than sufficient storage (6GB) for the songs that keep getting deleted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 11 how to prevent iBooks from moving my books to the cloud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327972/ios-11-how-to-prevent-ibooks-from-moving-my-books-to-the-cloud)

Comment: @anki thanks, I'll have to wait a while to see if that works for Books. But this list doesn't have Music in it